# Returning functions as a list in R

Tags: r

I am new to R and am currently learning it through **Hands on Programming with R**. Currently, I am unable to make sense of returning functions within a function as a list.
In the book the following code

```
setup <- function(deck) {
  DECK <- deck

  DEAL <- function() {
    card <- deck[1, ]
    assign("deck", deck[-1, ], envir = globalenv())
    card
  }

  SHUFFLE <- function(){
    random <- sample(1:52, size = 52)
    assign("deck", DECK[random, ], envir = globalenv())
 }

 list(deal = DEAL, shuffle = SHUFFLE)
}

cards <- setup(deck)
```

returns the fucntions deal and shuffle as a list which can be retrieved using the command `cards$deal` or `cards$shuffle`

I just want to replicate the same as an example and wrote the following code:

```
example <-function(){
  prnt1<-function(){
    x=1
    print(x)
  }
  prnt2<-function(){
    print("my name is x")
  }
  list(Print = prnt1, Print2 = prnt2)
}
```

However, now when I run `example()$Print`, I get the error

> Error in example() : argument "topic" is missing,
> with no default

or if I do `example$Print`, I get the error

> object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Can someone please explain why either of these errors happens in the example code while not in the former one?

Comment: I don’t know the book but the code you’ve posted from it isn’t very good, I’d caution against copying the bad habits it teaches (don’t assign into the global environment; also, the names inside the function follow weird conventions and the name `DECK` is completely redundant, and used inconsistently).

Comment: Hi! Thanks, for the advice about assinging into the global environment, also when I use a different name for the function instead of example, I am still not able to execute the command as it says,  "object of type 'closure' is not subsettable"? can you help with this please?

Comment: your code runs fine with me.

Comment: @CarTIC Like I wrote in my answer, that isn’t the issue. The issue is that you didn’t actually execute the function definition. You need to write it into the R console, or (better) save it in a file and source that in R.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I recognize the title, it's by Garrett Grolemund. This is from the section on scoping, so it's not necessarily what would be good coding habits in general, just understanding overwriting a global object https://rstudio-education.github.io/hopr/environments.html#closures

Answer (score 4):

The error message is telling you that you forgot to execute your function definition: `example` happens to be a name of a built-in function that has an argument `topic`.

But R allows you to override built-in functions, so that’s not an issue. The fact that you’re getting the error message means that *you didn’t override the function*. When you call `example()` it’s calling the built-in function rather than yours, which means that your function wasn’t defined.

Answer (score 0):

You can access those inner functions you put into a list like this.

```
example <- function(){
  prnt1 <- function(){
    x=1
    print(x)
  }
  prnt2 <- function(){
    print("my name is x")
  }
  list(Print = prnt1, Print2 = prnt2)
}

example2 <- example()

example2$Print()
[1] 1

example2$Print2()
[1] "my name is x"
```